# Get count leading zeros in a string

Tags: java

i need to get leading zeros in a string
example

```
1)s="0001254200"
  result=3
1)s="1254200"
  result=0
```

Is there is any way to achieve this in java .i know we can change string to character array and check each one.i am looking for alternate approch

Comment: Yes, there is. Why don't you try writing some code to achieve this? Why not capture the zeroes with regex then determine group size? This is likely to be slower than the array based approach you suggest.

Comment: What about a for loop?

Comment: What's wrong with your proposed way? There's a lot of ways to do it, and that seems pretty efficient and simple.

Comment: Try `s = s.replaceAll("^0+", "")`

Comment: why do you need an alternate approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could play with parsing back and forward the string into a number, for example **Integer.parseInt()** will ignore leading zeros

```
    final String xs = "0001254200";
    int i = xs.length() - String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(xs)).length();
    System.out.println(i);

    //Another option based on Titus comment

    i = xs.length() - xs.replaceAll("^0+", "").length();
    System.out.println(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your really want some fancy alternative you can try this (you need at least Java 9):

```
String s = "00012345";
long count = s.chars().takeWhile(c -> c == '0').count();
```

Comment: sorry there is nothing like chars.takenwhile in java9

Comment: are you sure you are using java 9? the official JDK is still in early access and the latest final release is still java 8...

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
    public class Main{
            public static void main(String[] args) {
                Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
                String str=s.next();
                int n=Integer.parseInt(str);
                String n1=Integer.toString(n);
                System.out.print(str.length()-n1.length());                              
                                                      }                               
                     }
```